# Less.js classes underlined as unknown in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less

I'm just starting with less.js. The classes I add to my .less files are underlined as unknown in visual studio 2013, but work fine. I would like VS to recognize these to allow navigation into the selected class.

[image]

Comment: are the css files generated from the less files included in the project?

Comment: I'm actually talking about classes in .less files. I was hoping VS will recognize these as well.

Comment: We need to see the Quick Action recommended when you hover over this in order to answer it. Though I have never seen this in VS 2013 (or 2017 or 2019).